# How to create a content type in drupal 7 to display the latest post on top

Tags: drupal, position, drupal-views, content-type, content-disposition

How to create a content type in  drupal 7 to display the latest post on top and the older one below in a seperate page when linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the Views module.

https://drupal.org/project/views

First, make a new content type, then make a new view for it, that lists it out (make a filter for that content type in Views UI), sorting in decrescent by submit date.